# Socket communication on a LAN environment

Tags: c#, tcpsocket

I have the following setup:

The server will connect via Bluetooth to several devices that are sending a discrete signal. Then there will be n clients that can inquiry the server (via web services probably) for which devices are connected and listen to the signal from the devices they want.

I think the best way to implement this is: when the server connects to a device via BT, it will open a Socket to a local port and send the data there. When a client ask for the available devices, the server will return a Dictionary and then the client just have to listen to that port.

But i'm having some problems with the socket implementation. How can I create and write the signal to a local port?

This is what I got so far:

```
class Device {
    ...
    public EndPoint Connect() {
        // create a bt connection to the device

        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_localIp), 0);
        _socket.Bind(endPoint);

        return endPoint;
    }

    private void OnBtDataReceived(object sender, wclDataEventArgs e) {
        _socket.Send(e.Data);
    }
}
```

But when reaching the _socket.Send(e.Data); I receive the following exception:

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Is this the right approach but it needs to have someone connected to the socket to read the data?

Comment: As the error says - the socket has no connection... what is it you want the socket to do with the data you are sending ? buffer it ? discard it ?

Comment: The data will be on real time so I want that any client that want's to read the data just connects to that port and read what's being written there. I don't know if TCP sockets is the best approach but I want something similar to online streaming.

Comment: If data loss is acceptable I would strongly recommend UDP broadcasting (which is "connectionless") - it works more like a "radio" and whoever wants to listen needs only to know which port to listen to...

Comment: Yes, either use UDP, which is a connectionless protocol, as Yahia suggested; or you could buffer the data in a MemoryStream (or some other buffering mechanism) and then send it when a client connects. If you want to "send and forget" as soon as the BT data is recieved, then I think UDP is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Yahia and Parmenion, gonna read some documentation on UDP broadcast and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UDP Broadcast as the comments suggest where you don't have to establish a connection. The server justs sends the data out on one port and any interested client can receive that data on that port.

If you want to distinguish between your devices you might have to broadcast every devices data  on a separate port. That might be a lot of (unnecessary) network traffic whn you have many devices.

The other option is using TCP.
Your server as to listen for incoming connections from your clients:

```
_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
_socket.Listen(10);
_socket.BeginAccept(onAccept, _socket);
```

In onAccept you have access to the clientsocket and can send data or store the reference to the socket somewhere to send data later on:

```
private static void onAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket clientSocket = ((Socket) ar.AsyncState).EndAccept(ar);

    // begin to accept the next client connection
    _socket.BeginAccept(onAccept, _socket);

    // this is the socket you can send data to the connected client:
    clientSocket.Send(data);
}
```

The TCP approach has the advantage that your server only sends data when there are connected clients and your server is aware of the number of clients connected.

Comment: I want to distinguish between devices but the worst case is 7 since BT won't allow more connections. The TPC approach seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

When using TCP, you don't need to call [`Bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx), but you need to call [`Connect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ych8bz3x.aspx).

```
_socket.Connect(endPoint);
```

This assumes that in your code `_localIp` is an IP address on the *local network* you want to connect to and not an IP address of a network adapter on the *local computer* that you want to use for the connection.

What `Bind()` does is to bind the socket to a local (i.e. on the current computer) end point. If you don't care what network adapter is used (which means you let the system decide that based on the target IP), and you also don't care what local port is used, there is no need to call `Bind()`.

Comment: _localIp is the local computer ip. I use bind() to assign a free port on the current computer. I don't care which port is used, I just want a free port to send the data there so that other computers will be able to fetch it.